# Conditional CSS Reactjs in Tab Navigation

Tags: css, reactjs

I have my custom tab navigation in React.js. I want to change the background color of the active tab using conditional rendering or state change. I tried passing state for color but nothing is changing in CSS. Here is my code link: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/reacttabs

Please help!

Answer (score 2):

you have to conditionally style the `li` element

first define a variable for active tab style

```
var active = Object.assign({},tabStyles);
    active.backgroundColor = '#000';
```

then inside the render conditionally call the desired style

```
<li style={this.state.active == '1' ? active  : tabStyles} onClick={() => {this.toggle('1')}}>A</li>
<li style={this.state.active == '2' ? active : tabStyles} onClick={() => {this.toggle('2')}}>B</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some errors, so here is a final working result

[RESULT](https://codesandbox.io/s/great-albattani-ucgii)